# Vim autocomplete to include punctuation between words

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I'm currently programming in Tcl/Tk. I have some widgets called `.entry,stdin` and `.entry,stdout` and I'm using [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) for autocompletion. The comma is there because I'm using a package called [gridplus](http://www.satisoft.com/tcltk/gridplus2) and that's how I can access the standard Tk widget functionality.

The idea of using autocompletion is that when I type `.entry,` and press the tab key it will show ONLY `stdin` and `stdout` as possible answers. However when I do that it shows all the possible words in the file instead of just `stdin` and `stdout`. And when I tried [autocomplpop](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoComplPop) and [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.vim) it doesn't even pop the menu after `.entry,`

I guess Vim is interpreting the `,` as a word separator even though there is no space. When I tried swapping `,` for `_` it works because I think Vim is interpreting it as one word. I guess it's got more to do with Vim's interpretation of what a word is, rather than a plugin matter. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `iskeyword` option to control how Vim decides what a word is. In your case, you can add a comma to it to tell Vim that your words consists of commas too:

```
:set iskeyword+=,
```

It's not perfect for your need but I think it's better than the default.

Check out `:help iskeyword` while you're at it.

Comment: Just tried this and repeated my experiment adding `this,what` to the dictionary and guess what?  It works. +1

Answer (score 1):

> I guess is more to do with vim interpretation of what a word is, rather than a plugin matter.

Not really, since the people who write the plugins presumably know what they are doing, and this behavior is on purpose and not by accident.  Unfortunately, it isn't what's good for you in this case.

The built-in completion (see `:help E535` and [omnicompletion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion) in the wiki), won't be any better either -- I notice it actually uses a comma as a separator for things in a dictionary, so if you add "this,what" it will include completion for "this" and "what" but not "this,what".  **[However, see holygeek's answer for the solution].**

What you want is not impossible -- the [omnicppcomplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520) will do completion for C++ on '.', '->', and '::', so why not one which does it for ','?  The problem is most likely no one has written anything alone those lines...

Comment: @milarepa : Don't bother, it's C++ specific, I was just using that as an illustration of what can be done. `holygeek`'s suggestion looks much more promising (guess I might be wrong about the significance of "what vim thinks a word is").